# MKMapView Swift : MKPointPointAnnotation Centre of screen

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to build a location selector in swift. The idea is :
When the map appears, an annotation pin appears at the user location. Then the user can change the location of the pin by moving the map around. (the pin stays at the centre of the screen. Like the uber app).

I have no issue spawning an annotation at the user location when the map loads. But I can't find a way to keep the pin at the centre of the screen when the user moves the map around.
I believe I must use regiondidChangeAnimated function, but I can`t find a way to update **smoothly** the position of the annotation.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I can't remember how its done specifically, but I did do this in a free course in which you build an app called on the map.... https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud421, that will show you how to do it. I'll see if i can find the specific code in my project

Comment: The easiest solution would be to cheat: Don't put the "center" pin on the map view at all. Put it on the map view's `superview` and disable the user interaction for that image view. Then, as the user pans the map below it, it just seamlessly floats there...

Comment: @Rob I believe that's the solution used in the above tutorial actually :)

Comment: @Scriptable, Rob, Neat ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want some view to not move when you pan the map, just put it on the map view's `superview` (e.g. add a `UIImageView` to that `superview`), add the necessary constraints so that it's centered where you want it, and make sure that user interaction is disabled with that image view. Then you can pan the map and the image view will gracefully float there, above the map, not moving at all.